# DropDown List error : "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

Trying to change my `view to PartialView`, that I use it with tabs System, I got this error : `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'REGION_ID'.` at line 30 of `_CreateCit.cshtml` file :

```
@model pfebs0.Models.CITOYEN

<h2>Demandeur Info</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)



        // some code removed (HTML tag)

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="REGION_ID" >Region</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("REGION_ID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.REGION_ID)
        </div>

// some other input tag 
        <br />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Valider</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Annuler</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    </div>
}
```

And this my `index.cshtml` file`:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Creation D'un nouveau Demande";
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Add user tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">add request tab</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
     <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
        @Html.Partial("_CreateCit", ViewData)
     </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
         @Html.Partial("_CreateDM")
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts {
    // script Section removed
}
```

her's my Controller code :

```
public ActionResult CreateCit()
    {
        ViewData["REGION_ID"] = new SelectList(db.REGION, "REGION_ID", "NOM");
        return PartialView("_CreateCit");
    }

    //
    // POST: /Citoyen/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateCit(CITOYEN citoyen)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CITOYEN.Add(citoyen);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.REGION_ID = new SelectList(db.REGION, "REGION_ID", "NOM", citoyen.REGION_ID);
        return PartialView(citoyen);
    }
```

The same code work with standard view, I just changed `return View` to `return PartialView(Viewname)` and I edited the cshtml file.
I think I missed something !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Html.Partial` just renders the partial view and does not call the controller action. It just takes the partial view code, without reaching the controller (set a break point in the action and test this). The `ViewData` will not contain the data that you think it will. You need to use `@Html.Action`:

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
    @Html.Action("CreateCit")
 </div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane"> 
     @Html.Action("CreateDM")
</div>
```

Alternatively, try explicitly adding the data in the `ViewData` object, before calling `@Html.Partial`:

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
    @{
          ViewData["REGION_ID_DDL"] = ViewData["REGION_ID"]
    }
    @Html.Partial("_CreateCit", ViewData)
 </div>
```

**Edit:**
To address your comment about the success message: there are several things you can do to display a success message. My personal favorite is to create a `ResultModel`:

```
public class ResultModel
{
     public string Message { get; set; }
     public ResultType TypeOfResult { get; set; }
}

public Enum TypeOfResult 
{
     Error,
     Success
}
```

Create a partial view which accepts a `ResultModel` and displays the message:

```
@model YourNamespace.Models.ResultModel

<p>Sort du resultat: @Model.TypeOfResult</p>
<p>Message: @Model.Message</p>
```

You would then just call it like this:

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     db.CITOYEN.Add(citoyen);
     db.SaveChanges();

     ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();
     resultModel.TypeOfResult = TypeOfResult.Success;
     //my french is a bit rusty but the result from Google Translate sounds good enough
     resultModel.Message = "Citoyen ajouté avec succès.";


     return PartialView("_ResultSummary", resultModel);
 }
```

Of course, this can be used to trace out errors as well. You could add a `try-catch` around  the `db.SaveChanges();` call and set the success type/message in the `try` block and the error type/message in the `catch` block.

Another advantage of this method is that the `ResultModel` object can also be sent as a JSON string, in case you want to display a JavaScript "alert" or even a custom pop-up.

Comment: thank you so much you sloved my problem using first one, but now I got this error `System.InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.` But data are added to my database succesfully, in stead having redirection how to show succes messages ?

Comment: Hmm... yes, that might be a problem. I'm sorry to say, I can't think of anything right now. The data is successfully saved because the problem comes from `return RedirectToAction("Index");` which is being called after the database changes are committed.

Comment: @Chlebta, the only thing that I can come up with is redirecting from the partial view instead. Create a "redirecting partial view" and call it with Index address. In the partial view you would have something like: `@{ Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");}`. Please note that this is not tested, it's just an idea.

Comment: instead of redirection I want to show success message, Any way to do it ?

Comment: ResultModel is simple model ? because ResultType is unkown Type and for Enum I got `expected classn delegate, enum, interface or struct`?

Comment: Enum problem Sloved by `enum` First letter LowerCase not UpperCase