# ASP.net MVC Success Alert After Form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display success Alert pop-up or alert message after form submited and action succeded 
 
In this example I want to show "successfully add" :
 `Create Action` :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(TAUX taux)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TAUX.Add(taux);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CAT_ID = new SelectList(db.CATEGORIE, "CAT_ID", "LIBELLE", taux.CAT_ID);
        ViewBag.C_GARANT = new SelectList(db.GARANTIE, "C_GARANT", "LIB_ABREGE", taux.C_GARANT);
        return PartialView("_Create", taux);
    }
```

`Index Action` :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var taux = db.TAUX.Include(t => t.CATEGORIE).Include(t => t.GARANTIE);
            return View(taux.ToList());
        }
```

What should I add to do this ?

Comment: @MikeSW I have tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360008/dropdown-list-error-there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlist) but i got some issue because I want to show succes message in my Index view for example not in seperated PartialView

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, for sure, but implementation details might change from technologies and app structure.

One of the most common ways for doing this (and the one I'm currently using with great success) is to receive whater-you-need-to-receive and return a JSON object with the status and/or error message, which will be used by some script on your view.

For example:

```
[Route(""), HttpPost]
public JsonResult DoSomethingOnTheServer(DoSomethingViewModel vm)
{
   try
   {
      if (DoSomething(vm)) return Success();
      else return Error("The server wasn't able to do something right now.");
   }
   catch (Exception err)
   {
      return Error(err.Message);
   }
}

public JsonResult Success() { return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "" }); }
public JsonResult Error(string message) { return Json(new { Success = false, Message = message }); }
```

This way, you can do something like:

```
<script>
   $.ajax({
      url: "/",
      method: "POST",
      data: getMyData(),

      success: function(json) {
         if (json.Success) {
            alert("Wow, everything was fine!");
         } else {
            alert(json.Message);
         }
      },

      // This will be trigered whenever your ajax call fails (broken ISP link, etc).
      error: function() {
         alert("Something went wrong. Maybe the server is offline?");
      }
   });
</script>
```

Being honest with you, it's possible to submit the form (regular submit, I mean) and on the page refresh, display whatever you want.

This will, however, force you to load something extra with your view model, like an extra `<script>` tag or some extra `<div>` tags and to check for that every time.

From a usability/design point-of-view, it's a no-go. Avoid page refresh whenever possible because they give a feeling for the user that the app is either going away or that he/she is now moving outsinde the app.

Also, from a performance point-of-view, "full round-trips" to the server, consisting of sending the form data and retrieving a whole new page (with the whole layout, scripts, razor rendering/parse and all) is a massive problem just to show "success/fail" for the end-user so, again: avoid it whenever possible.

IMHO, returning either a view or a partial view *only to display a message to the end-user* is just wasting **both** yours **and** your end-users' link.

Comment: thank you, but the Ajax script where To put it ? in my partialView where my form, or in Index view ?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't properly answer that in an easy fashion here. Would be too broad. That changes from where you've placed your jQuery ref, if you'd like to bind this wither to the submit button or directly hook into the form's submit method, if you'd have a form at all, etc. Maybe some Googleing' into hooking that to your form submit might help, but again, that changes a lot from your context. Sounds like a good candidate for *another* question now...

Comment: I puted this the `Ajax Script` in My PartialView but now when I click on the Add button bootstrap modal dosn'y appears any more

Comment: Also `Route("")` is not known and it is not dectecting to wich nameSpace it belong

Comment: Please take look over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665351/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-succes-message

Answer (score 2):

I used to make **Ajax Form** and in the **OnSuccess** fucntion i show message :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit1", "Availability", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId = "formAddAvailabilityContainer", OnSuccess = "AddAvailabilitySuccess" }, new { @class = "AjaxForm", @id = "formAvailability_" + Model.Id }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)




        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime)
        @Html.MyValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime)
        @Html.MyValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecurrenceFreq)
        @Html.MyValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecurrenceFreq)



      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndsAfterValue, new {id="txtBoxEndsAfterValue" })
     @Html.MyValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndsAfterValue)



    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndsByDate)


    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="btnsubmit" />
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnCancelAvailability" id="0" value="Cancel">


    }


 <script>

    function AddAvailabilitySuccess()
    {

    alert("Record updated successfully!");

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: On my Controller I Have to change my Action or not ?

Comment: yes instead of redirecting return empty result or partialview

Comment: Can you explain me this part `UpdateTargetId = "formAddAvailabilityContainer",OnSuccess = "AddAvailabilitySuccess" },new { @class = "AjaxForm", @id = "formAvailability_" + Model.Id }))` . Sorry I'm beginner

Comment: updatetargetid means id of some element on which mostly div in which returned ressult of ajax post is shown and OnSuccess means on ajax form post success call exaecute this javascript function and next after comma are html attrobutes of form which is class and id

Comment: for details:http://mvc3only.blogspot.com/2012/04/aspnet-mvc3-ajax-form-submission-simple.html

Comment: can I get your mail please?

Comment: ehsansajjad465@yahoo.com

Comment: in my app I'm using PartialView and Bootstrap Modal so in UpdateTargeTId should i put ID of my ModalContainer ?

Comment: if you want to load partial view html in that container then yes

Answer (score 2):

I have a way to do this, using the ViewBag.

In your controller you must add:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TAUX.Add(taux);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.SuccessMsg = "successfully added";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Then in the Index view:

```
@{
    var message = ViewBag.SuccessMsg;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = '@message';
    if(message){
        alert(message);
    }
</script>
```

in the end you use JavaScript mixed with the MVC ViewBag :)